# Display image with a zoom = 1 with Matplotlib imshow() (how to?)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to display an image (say 800x800) with Matplotlib.pyplot imshow() function but I want to display it so that one pixel of the image occupies one pixel on the screen (zoom factor = 1, no shrink, no stretch).

I'm a beginner, so do you know how to proceed?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Matplotlib isn't optimized for this.  You'd be a bit better off with simpler options if you just want to display an image at one-pixel-to-one-pixel.  (Have a look at Tkinter, for example.)

That having been said:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# DPI, here, has _nothing_ to do with your screen's DPI.
dpi = 80.0
xpixels, ypixels = 800, 800

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(ypixels/dpi, xpixels/dpi), dpi=dpi)
fig.figimage(np.random.random((xpixels, ypixels)))
plt.show()
```

Or, if you really want to use `imshow`, you'll need to be a bit more verbose.  However, this has the advantage of allowing you to zoom in, etc if desired.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

dpi = 80
margin = 0.05 # (5% of the width/height of the figure...)
xpixels, ypixels = 800, 800

# Make a figure big enough to accomodate an axis of xpixels by ypixels
# as well as the ticklabels, etc...
figsize = (1 + margin) * ypixels / dpi, (1 + margin) * xpixels / dpi

fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize, dpi=dpi)
# Make the axis the right size...
ax = fig.add_axes([margin, margin, 1 - 2*margin, 1 - 2*margin])

ax.imshow(np.random.random((xpixels, ypixels)), interpolation='none')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, I'll take a look at that. Frankly, I hadn't though about Tkinter but it could do the job. I'll look at it. Maybe it will solve my problem.

Comment: I suggested Tk mostly because it's in the standard library... If your image is already a numpy array, a great option is `glumpy`.  http://code.google.com/p/glumpy/ I think `pygame` also has a lot of similar functionality, if you don't want to take the route of a full-blown gui toolkit.  Good luck, at any rate!

Comment: Joe, the first method with figimage() do **perfectly** the job. The key words are "adds a non-resampled array *X* to the figure." in the help... I need to display non-resampled black-and-white dithered image.

Comment: the other options don't have the ability to zoom or view coordinates as you hover mouse though?

Comment: @endolith - True! That's one of the large advantages to the second example.

Comment: I tried both methods with a 360-by-631 ndarray of float64 values, with matplotlib 1.5 in jupyter notebook. Neither method produced a non-resampled, non-interpolated graph. What am I missing?

Comment: @Kal - If you're using the inline or nbagg backends in an IPython notebook, they're completely different than "normal" matplotlib with regards to figure size.  The figure size controls work a bit differently. I'd recommend avoiding inline figures in notebooks, unless you're wanting to make a static document.   (Actually, I'd recommend avoiding notebooks altogether and just use "regular" IPython instead, but I'm an outlier in that regard.)

Comment: @JoeKington I see. Ah well, I was so frustrated that I have resorted to using the matplotlib colormaps directly and displaying the array using Pillow instead.

Comment: a small mistake:
figsize = x, y (not y,x)
so in the figsize line xpixels and ypixels should be replaced

Comment: I wish I could downvote this answer but my upvote is locked in. Be _very careful_ if you use this. The `800, 800` need to be set to _precisely_ the size of your image plus the margin for this to give the one-to-one pixel behavior. If they're too large, you'll get stretching. If they're too small, it will drop pixels from your image. I wasted an entire day trying to debug a gap in my data that turned out to be an artifact of this display code (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69398683/extract-street-network-from-a-raster-image)). Just use `Image.fromarray` instead.

Comment: I think the margin needs to be multiplied by 2 in the figsize too. Also, you need to add `1` to `xpixels` and `ypixels` to account for the black border, which it seems also counts towards the axes size.

Comment: Also you should be multiplying by `1/(1 + 2 * margin)` not `1 - 2 * margin`. The latter makes it slightly off

Answer (score 7):

If you don't really need matlibplot, here is the best way for me

```
import PIL.Image
from io import BytesIO
import IPython.display
import numpy as np
def showbytes(a):
    IPython.display.display(IPython.display.Image(data=a))

def showarray(a, fmt='png'):
    a = np.uint8(a)
    f = BytesIO()
    PIL.Image.fromarray(a).save(f, fmt)
    IPython.display.display(IPython.display.Image(data=f.getvalue()))
```

use `showbytes()` for show a image bytes string, and `showarray()` for show a numpy array.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working in a Jupyter notebook, have [`pillow`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) (Python Imaging Library) installed, and don't need a colormap, then [`Image.fromarray`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html?highlight=fromarray#PIL.Image.fromarray) is convenient. You'll just need to get your data into a form it can use (`np.uint8` or `bool`):

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
data = np.random.random((512, 512))

Image.fromarray((255 * data).astype(np.uint8))
```

[image: Jupyter cell showing noise]

or if you have a boolean array:

```
Image.fromarray(data > 0.5)
```

[image: Jupyter cell showing binary noise]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified version of the accepted answer using `imshow`, which worked for me, at least for square images (it seems to not always work for non-square images). The math seems to be off for the accepted answer.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

image = ...

dpi = 100
margin = 0.05
ypixels, xpixels = image.shape
fig = plt.figure(figsize=((1 + margin * 2) * (xpixels + 1) / dpi,
                          (1 + margin * 2) * (ypixels + 1) / dpi),
                 dpi=dpi)
ax = fig.add_axes([margin, margin,
                   1 / (1 + margin * 2), 1 / (1 + margin * 2)])
ax.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

The differences between this and the accepted answer are the width and height of the axes being different, as well as the figsize adding `1` to each dimension as well as multiplying the `margin` by `2`.

Answer (score -2):

If you are trying to zoom in your image, then:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

dpi = 80
margin = 0.01 # The smaller it is, the more zoom you have
xpixels, ypixels = your_image.shape[0], your_image.shape[1] ## 

figsize = (1 + margin) * ypixels / dpi, (1 + margin) * xpixels / dpi

fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize, dpi=dpi)
ax = fig.add_axes([margin, margin, 1 - 2*margin, 1 - 2*margin])

ax.imshow(your_image)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The image displays too small.