# Draw or resize plotted quantized image with nearest neighbour scaling

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, quantization

Following this example of [K means clustering](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/05/26/opencv-python-k-means-color-clustering/) I want to recreate the same - only I'm very keen for the final image to contain just the quantized colours (+ white background). As it is, the colour bars get smooshed together to create a pixel line of blended colours.

[image: quantization image]

Whilst they look very similar, the image (top half) is what I've got from CV2 it contains 38 colours total.
The lower image only has 10 colours and is what I'm after.

Let's look at a bit of that with 6 times magnification:

[image: close up]

I've tried :

```
# OpenCV and Python K-Means Color Clustering
# build a histogram of clusters and then create a figure
# representing the number of pixels labeled to each color
hist = colour_utils.centroid_histogram(clt)
bar = colour_utils.plot_colors(hist, clt.cluster_centers_)
bar = cv2.resize(bar, (460, 345), 0, 0, interpolation = cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
```

However, the resize seems to have no resizing effect or change the scaling type. I don't know what controls the initial image size either.
Confused.

Any ideas?

Comment: Always best to present an image of the issue. "A picture is worth a 1000 words."

Comment: @fmw42 Not sure if SO allows questions in comic book format :)

Comment: Answer below from @Rotem make sense to me. Any tool that resizes may cause blending of colors. So save with cv2.imwrite(), not pyplot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to show the image using `cv2.imshow`, instead of using `matplotlib`.

`cv2.imshow` shows the image "pixel to pixel" by default, while `matplotlib.pyplot` matches the image dimensions to the size of the axes.

```
bar_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(bar, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)  # Convert RGB to BGR
cv2.imshow('bar', bar_bgr)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

In case you want to use `matplotlib`, take a look at: [Display image with a zoom = 1 with Matplotlib imshow() (how to?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056458/display-image-with-a-zoom-1-with-matplotlib-imshow-how-to).

---

Code used for testing:

```
# import the necessary packages
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import argparse
#import utils
import cv2

def centroid_histogram(clt):
    # grab the number of different clusters and create a histogram
    # based on the number of pixels assigned to each cluster
    numLabels = np.arange(0, len(np.unique(clt.labels_)) + 1)
    (hist, _) = np.histogram(clt.labels_, bins = numLabels)
    # normalize the histogram, such that it sums to one
    hist = hist.astype("float")
    hist /= hist.sum()
    # return the histogram
    return hist

def plot_colors(hist, centroids):
    # initialize the bar chart representing the relative frequency
    # of each of the colors
    bar = np.zeros((50, 300, 3), dtype = "uint8")
    startX = 0
    # loop over the percentage of each cluster and the color of
    # each cluster
    for (percent, color) in zip(hist, centroids):
        # plot the relative percentage of each cluster
        endX = startX + (percent * 300)
        cv2.rectangle(bar, (int(startX), 0), (int(endX), 50),
            color.astype("uint8").tolist(), -1)
        startX = endX
    
    # return the bar chart
    return bar


# load the image and convert it from BGR to RGB so that
# we can dispaly it with matplotlib
image = cv2.imread('chelsea.png')
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
# show our image
plt.figure()
plt.axis("off")
plt.imshow(image)

# reshape the image to be a list of pixels
image = image.reshape((image.shape[0] * image.shape[1], 3))

# cluster the pixel intensities
clt = KMeans(n_clusters = 5)
clt.fit(image)


# build a histogram of clusters and then create a figure
# representing the number of pixels labeled to each color
hist = centroid_histogram(clt)
bar = plot_colors(hist, clt.cluster_centers_)
# show our color bart
#plt.figure()
#plt.axis("off")
#plt.imshow(bar)
#plt.show()

bar = cv2.resize(bar, (460, 345), 0, 0, interpolation = cv2.INTER_NEAREST)

bar_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(bar, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)  # Convert RGB to BGR
cv2.imshow('bar', bar_bgr)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```