# Extract street network from a raster image

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image, hough-transform

I have a 512x512 image of a street grid:

[image: Street grid]

I'd like to extract polylines for each of the streets in this image (large blue dots = intersections, small blue dots = points along polylines):

[image: Street grid with polylines]

I've tried a few techniques! One idea was to start with [`skeletonize`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.morphology.html#skeletonize) to compress the streets down to 1px wide lines:

```py
from skimage import morphology
morphology.skeletonize(streets_data))
```

[image: Skeletonized streets]

Unfortunately this has some gaps that break the connectivity of the street network; I'm not entirely sure why, but my guess is that this is because some of the streets are 1px narrower in some places and 1px wider in others. ***(update: the gaps aren't real; they're entirely artifacts of how I was displaying the skeleton. See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056458/display-image-with-a-zoom-1-with-matplotlib-imshow-how-to/69453359#comment122759502_8057182) for the sad tale. The skeleton is well-connected.)***

I can patch these using a `binary_dilation`, at the cost of making the streets somewhat variable width again:

```py
out = morphology.skeletonize(streets_data)
out = morphology.binary_dilation(out, morphology.selem.disk(1))
```

[image: re-connected streets]

With a re-connected grid, I can run the Hough transform to find line segments:

```py
import cv2
rho = 1  # distance resolution in pixels of the Hough grid
theta = np.pi / 180  # angular resolution in radians of the Hough grid
threshold = 8  # minimum number of votes (intersections in Hough grid cell)
min_line_length = 10  # minimum number of pixels making up a line
max_line_gap = 2  # maximum gap in pixels between connectable line segments

# Run Hough on edge detected image
# Output "lines" is an array containing endpoints of detected line segments
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(
    out, rho, theta, threshold, np.array([]),
    min_line_length, max_line_gap
)

line_image = streets_data.copy()
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
        cv2.line(line_image,(x1,y1),(x2,y2), 2, 1)
```

This produces a whole jumble of overlapping line segments, along with some gaps (look at the T intersection on the right side):

[image: Results of Hough]

At this point I could try to de-dupe overlapping line segments, but it's not really clear to me that this is a path towards a solution, especially given that gap.

Are there more direct methods available to get at the network of polylines I'm looking for? In particular, what are some methods for:

1. Finding the intersections (both four-way and T intersections).
2. Shrinking the streets to all be 1px wide, allowing that there may be some variable width.
3. Finding the polylines between intersections.

Comment: You could give [this](https://github.com/05dirnbe/nefi) a try.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to improve your "skeletonization", you could try the following algorithm to obtain the "1-px wide streets":

```py
import imageio
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage import distance_transform_edt
from skimage.segmentation import watershed

# read image
image_rgb = imageio.imread('1mYBD.png')

# convert to binary
image_bin = np.max(image_rgb, axis=2) > 0

# compute the distance transform (only > 0)
distance = distance_transform_edt(image_bin)

# segment the image into "cells" (i.e. the reciprocal of the network)
cells = watershed(distance)

# compute the image gradients
grad_v = np.pad(cells[1:, :] - cells[:-1, :], ((0, 1), (0, 0)))
grad_h = np.pad(cells[:, 1:] - cells[:, :-1], ((0, 0), (0, 1)))

# given that the cells have a constant value,
# only the edges will have non-zero gradient
edges = (abs(grad_v) > 0) + (abs(grad_h) > 0)

# extract points into (x, y) coordinate pairs
pos_v, pos_h = np.nonzero(edges)

# display points on top of image
plt.imshow(image_bin, cmap='gray_r')
plt.scatter(pos_h, pos_v, 1, np.arange(pos_h.size), cmap='Spectral')
```

[image: output]

The algorithm works on the "blocks" rather than the "streets", take a look into the `cells` image:

[image: cells]

Comment: Using watershed to find the midpoints of the lines is plain brilliant. I guess this only identifies the precise midline if the cells are approximately the same size? Seems that way at the 3-way junctions. Still a worthy trade-off, IMO.

Comment: I think this is independent of cell size. it should find the midlines within the gaps between cells. you could try an experiment on a hand-drawn input.

Comment: Thanks for this! See the update to my question. Sadly the code I was using to display the skeleton had a bug that made it _look_ like there were gaps, even though there were none. In reality the skeleton is connected. `skimage.morphology.skeleton` works a bit better than this approach because it doesn't require a "block" on either side of every street, e.g. for the street that trails off at the bottom center of the image in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was on the right track with `skeleton`; it *does* produce a connected, 1px wide version of the street grid. It's just that there was a bug in my display code (see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056458/display-image-with-a-zoom-1-with-matplotlib-imshow-how-to/69453359#comment122759502_8057182)). Here's what the skeleton actually looks like:

```
from skimage import morphology
morphology.skeletonize(streets_data))
```

[image: Skeleton without gaps]

From here the reference to [NEFI2](https://github.com/05dirnbe/nefi) in RJ Adriaansen's comment was extremely helpful. I wasn't able to get an extraction pipeline to run on my image using their GUI, but I was able to cobble together something using their code and approach.

Here's the general procedure I wound up with:

- Find candidate nodes. These are pixels in the skeleton with either one neighbor (end of a line) or 3+ neighbors (an intersection). NEFI2 calls this the Zhang-Suen algorithm. For four-way intersections, it produces multiple nodes so we need to merge them.
- Repeat until no two nodes are too close together:

  - Use breadth-first search (flood fill) to connect nodes.
  - If two connected nodes are within D of each other, merge them.
- Run shapely's [`simplify`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.simplify) on the paths between nodes to get polylines.

I put this all together in a repo here: [extract-raster-network](https://github.com/danvk/extract-raster-network).

This works pretty well on my test images! Here are some sample images:

[image: Extracted street network 1]

[image: Extracted street network 2]